How to better include the optional filtering conditions for URL of API calls
When working with API calls, we need to edit the URL.
We typically can add many options for filtering in the URL.
For example, if I have two optional filtering conditions (lane_id and workflow_id), then I can stupidly write the following for all the possible combinations:
def get_cards(board_id, lane_id=None, workflow_id=None):
    """ Get the all the cards by the given conditions """

    if lane_id is None and workflow_id is None:
        url = f'https://xxxx.kanbanize.com/api/v2/cards?board_ids={board_id}'
    if lane_id and workflow_id:
        url = f'https://xxxx.kanbanize.com/api/v2/cards?board_ids={board_id}&lane_ids={lane_id}&workflow_ids={workflow_id}'
    if lane_id and workflow_id is None:
        url = f'https://xxxx.kanbanize.com/api/v2/cards?board_ids={board_id}&lane_ids={lane_id}'
    if lane_id is None and workflow_id:
        url = f'https://xxxx.kanbanize.com/api/v2/cards?board_ids={board_id}&workflow_ids={workflow_id}'

The problem is, when the number of options grows, the number of the possible combinations will soar.
Is there any easier way to write the options into the URL

This is the way for another approach.
def get_cards(board_id, lane_id=None, workflow_id=None):
    """Get all the cards by the given conditions"""
    
    base_url = f'https://xxxx.kanbanize.com/api/v2/cards'
    
    # Create a dictionary of query parameters
    params = {
        'board_ids': board_id,
        'lane_ids': lane_id,
        'workflow_ids': workflow_id
    }
    
    # Build the query string by including only the non-None parameters
    query_string = '&'.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in params.items() if value is not None)
    
    # Construct the full URL
    url = f'{base_url}?{query_string}'
    
    return url


I usually go with:
def get_cards(**kwargs):
   base_url = 'https://xxxx.kanbanize.com/api/v2/cards'
   add = '&'.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in kwargs.items())
   if add:
       return base_url + "?" + add
   return base_url

final_url = get_cards(board_id=1,lane_ids=2)

With this you can decide what gets included directly in the call. Alternatively you could also provide the dict directly and dont use the python own kwarg dict
